# Mysql CALL procedure INTO OUTFILE

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, procedure

I have a procedure that I want to store its results into a file.
The thing is, I don't want to edit the procedure and add

```
INTO OUTFILE 'name-of-file'
```

But instead want to store it when I call that procedure.
I have tried so far

```
CALL procedure(variables) INTO OUTFILE 'nof'
```

and

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'nof' FROM CALL procedure(variables)
```

Comment: What were the results from what you've tried?

Comment: I got "possible malformed SQL query"